# How to reveal old versions of a row in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, mvcc

I know that Postgres uses MVCC and stores older versions of rows on disk. I would like to access (read-only) some old, discarded versions of a concrete row. How can I do it?

Comment: Here is similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325067/is-it-possible-to-access-an-old-version-of-a-row-in-postgres-that-hasnt-been-vac

Comment: @Grzegorz thanks. I found it was possible with pg_filedump, except for vacuumed rows. Something like http://fossplanet.com/f15/%5Bgeneral%5D-rows-missing-table-despite-fk-constraint-34240/index2.html

Answer (score 3):

In PostgreSQL 9.1 and later, the best solution for this is https://github.com/omniti-labs/pgtreats/tree/master/contrib/pg_dirtyread which is an extension that provides a functional interface in sql to access old, unvacuumed versions of rows.  Other tools may exist for other dbs.  This works well for a number of cases data recovery, just exploring the utility of mvcc, and the like.  With some effort it might work on earlier versions.